# Azure alerts not being sent out

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone know why alerts in azure are not being sent out?

I have alerts set up on my webhosting plan:

[image]

However the alerts (that is an email) never gets sent out - so I never know about important actions in relation to my web application.

Is this a problem with azure? A bug?

Comment: All alerts, or just some alerts?

Comment: All alerts. Not getting a single one